# Getting an iFrameResize not defined error in AngularJS

Tags: iframe-resizer

I am trying to use the code at: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

In my index.html page I have included (and it does load):

```
<script src="./Scripts/iframeResizer.js"></script>
```

In my iframe content page I have included:

```
<script src="iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

My AngularJS controller is:

```
ajs_module.controller("MyController",
        ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {

            $scope.iframeLoadedCallBack = function () {
                console.log('Resizing iFrame...');
                iFrameResize({ log: true }); // causes: Uncaught ReferenceError: iFrameResize is not defined
            }
}])
```

When the host page loads and tries to resize the iFrame, I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: iFrameResize is not defined
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing `window.iFrameResize`? as it looks like a scoping issue.

Failing that load it in with require js

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me in Angular 11

Comment: It's good to vote up answer that you find helpful

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses JqLite instead of the normal  jquery, probably you need to add jquery before loading the  iframeResizer.js script

if you cant access a global function it should be because is not initializated

(check other dependendies but i didnt find anything else in the iframeResize page)

Comment: I do load jQuery: <script src="./Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>  Thanks.